# F5 load banacer file format

Tags: file, structure, f5

I'm working with a pice of exported configuration from an F5 Load Balancer. I need help to identified if this structure is something like YAML, JSON or some similar structure.

The extract looks like this:

```
ltm pool Some_Name {
    members {
        192.168.0.199:http {
            address 192.168.0.199
            session user-disabled
            state down
        }
        192.168.0.200:http {
            address 192.168.0.200
            session user-disabled
            state down
        }
        192.168.0.207:http {
            address 192.168.0.207
            session monitor-enabled
            state up
        }
        192.168.0.214:http {
            address 192.168.0.214
            session monitor-enabled
            state up
        }
    }
    monitor gateway_icmp
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is F5 BIG-IP's own configuration structure. They copied this snippet from the /config/bigip.conf file on their device.